# Infragistics XamGrid with different row heights

Tags: height, row, infragistics, xamgrid

I have a XamGrid that I've got displaying several dynamically generated columns, and one of those columns can have a listbox in it that sizes itself according to how many items are in it (but has a maximum height constraint). I want each row of the XamGrid to basically only be as large as it needs to be - which they are at first, but after scrolling up and down the contents of the grid a bit I find that rows that had hardly any values in the listbox (so should be fairly small in height) are now the same height as the largest rows I've scrolled into view previously. The result is a lot of wasted space, so I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to make it so that the rows don't automatically resize themselves to match the largest row that has been loaded. I've tried taking a look at the control template but all I see in it are 3 parts and can't see any way to edit or look inside those parts.

PS I would have posted this on Infragistics own support forums but I can't for the life of me actually find any way to post new topics on there even when signed in with my IG account... great design.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: When signed into the Infragistics WebSite, there should be a "Write a New Post" button under the search box in the forum:http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/373.aspx  For the question that you are asking about the listbox, can you provide the markup or code that sets up the column?  Also, is this WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that you only see the Write New Post button when you go into a sub forum within the "NetAdvantage for WPF" forum. I'll post the question on there and provide the XAML I'm using

Comment: It may also be worth expanding on your answer here with the code so that anyone viewing this question may be able to help you as well.

Comment: @Chris128 Did you end up getting a solution? I don't think my issue is exactly the same as yours but the solution I found basically allows row heights to be dynamically resolved even if you change the items (and require more space) in the grid. I will post it if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `RowHeight` property to `Dynamic`.  That should take care of the issue for you.

```
<ig:XamGrid RowHeight="Dynamic" ... >
```